# Ensure non-mocked methods are not called in mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

In the following example:

```
   Execution execution = mock(Execution.class);
   when(execution.getLastQty()).thenReturn(1000.0);
   when(execution.getLastPrice()).thenReturn(75.0);

   order.onFillReceived(execution);

   assertEquals(0, order.getLeavesQty(), 0);
```

Execution has many other methods that should not be called. Only the two methods that have been mocked should be used within this test and should be called. If any other methods are called, then the test should fail.

How to I tell Mockito to fail if any other methods are called?

Comment: Why would you want to?  If the `Order` class happens to call other methods of the `Execution` class, and it doesn't affect the outcome of the behaviour that you're testing, then why would you want the test to fail?

Comment: In this particular case ... let's say that order.onFillReceived winds up assigning order.getLeavesQty based on the method from execution.getWrongQty(). Because getWrongQty will return the default value for that method (0), the assert will still work even though getLeavesQty isn't being set by the right value. This is only because the default for wrong values is the same value as what is being asserted in the test.

Comment: I don't quite follow that.  But wouldn't it be cleaner to choose values for the test that can't easily happen by accident?  So that if the test passes, you know that the calculation has happened correctly.  If the test doesn't demonstrate that the correct value was calculated (rather than happening by accident), I would question the value of the test.

Answer (score 9):

The [documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#8) covers this explicitly. You want to call `verifyNoMoreInteractions`, either after calling `verify` (as per the docs) or

```
verify(execution).getLastQty();
verify(execution).getLastPrice();
verifyNoMoreInteractions(execution);
```

or using `ignoreStubs`:

```
verifyNoMoreInteractions(ignoreStubs(execution));
```

Comment: Adding this fails the test complaining that ... No Interactions Wanted Here.

Comment: On the flip side ... if ignoreStubs is used (available in 1.9), the above works correctly. The actual code is         verifyNoMoreInteractions(ignoreStubs(execution));

Comment: @user465342: Well that depends on what you were trying to do. You haven't shown what `onFillReceived` does - I suspect that if it only calls `getLastQty()` and `getLastPrice()` once each, then the above would be fine, I believe. But yes, if you want to treat those as stub methods then `ignoreStubs` looks like the right way to go.

Comment: If you want to use `verifyNoMoreInteractions` without using `ignoreStubs` as per @JonSkeet's answer, you'd have to actually put `verify` calls in for the method calls that you are expecting (presumably `getLastQty` and `getLastPrice` once each).  Otherwise, the test will fail if these methods have been called.  However, I'm not quite brave enough to downvote SO royalty! :-)

Comment: @DavidWallace: Thanks for the detail. Will edit the answer. (Can you check that it looks correct now?)

Comment: @JonSkeet - Looks great now, so I'm giving you +1.  My earlier comment is now invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the never method if that fits the use case:

i.e.

```
verify(execution, never()).someOtherMethod();
```